# How to start a batch file on USB remove?

Tags: windows, autorun

I would like to run a batch file on Unplug of a USB Drive.

Using AutoRun.inf we can start a batch file on USB insert.

But not sure how to execute it on USB Remove.

Comment: Where would this batch file be located? You'd have to copy it to the users disk.

Comment: Yes the batch file would be present on the users disk.

Answer (score 0):

Not using autorun.inf for sure. You'll have to an application coded and running that will respond to usb devices removed, which won't help with your situation i think.

Comment: Ya surely this wont help me. As i need to run the application on all users desk. I just want to show up a Website when ever an user removes his USB drive. Is there any way around for this?